# How to detect if iframe open and jump to ios native app sucessfully or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iframe

I used iframe to automatically jump to iOS native app when user opens our site on mobile browser. It works fine. If app is not installed then it'll just stay on the browser.

`<iframe id="my-iframe" class="hidden" src="app:///" ></iframe>`

Now I have a question about tracking if the app is opened successfully or not.

I tried with approach: wait for 4s, then check if the iframe's ready state. However, it seems that even if app is not opened up, the state will still be "ready". 
I'm asking here to see if there is any good way to detect iframe open native app successfully or not.

```
setTimeout(function () {
            var ifr=document.getElementById("my-iframe");
            if (ifr.contentWindow.document.readyState == 'complete' || ifr.contentWindow.document.readyState == 'interactive') {
                console.log('iframe load success');
            } else {
                console.log('iframe load failed');
            }
        }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ifr=document.getElementById("my-iframe");

ifr.onload = function(){
    console.log('iframe load success');
}
```

Comment: no, the onload handler never get called even if the iframe "src" is loaded (native app opened).

Comment: sorry want to correct my previous comment. The onload function do get executed. However it'll be executed no matter whether native app is opened or not (not installed). so this function doesn't provide good information.